# how to get month wise data in datagridview with local datatable in c#

Tags: c#-4.0

```
public partial class logRead : Form
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable tab = new DataTable();

    public logRead()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    string line;
    private void BtnUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        DataRow[] filteredRows = tab.Select("Username = '"+cmbUsername.Text+"'");
        DataTable dt = filteredRows.CopyToDataTable();
        dgv1.DataSource = dt;
        txtcount.Text = dgv1.Rows.Count.ToString();         
    }

    private void btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dtmDate.CustomFormat = "dd MMM yyyy hh mm ss";
        DataRow[] filteredRows = tab.Select("Datetime = '" +dtmDate.Text + "'");
         DataTable dt = filteredRows.CopyToDataTable();
        dgv1.DataSource = dt;                   
    }

    private void logRead_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StreamReader strRead = new StreamReader("D:\\login.hml");
        string line;
        line = strRead.ReadToEnd();
        DataRow row = null;
        tab.Columns.Add("Ipaddress");
        tab.Columns.Add("Sysname");
        tab.Columns.Add("Username");
        tab.Columns.Add("Text");
        tab.Columns.Add("Datetime");
        string[] rows = line.Split(new char[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach (string r in rows)
        {
            string[] columns = r.Split(new char[] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            if (columns.Length <= tab.Columns.Count)
            {
                row = tab.NewRow();

                for (int i = 0; i < columns.Length; i++)

                    row[i] = columns[i];
                tab.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }
        ds.Tables.Add(tab);
        dgv1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        txtcount.Text = dgv1.Rows.Count.ToString();
    }
}}
```

i have alogfile ,when form load itself i  write code to fill datagridview ,i use temporarly datatable and dataset and filling in to datagridview ,and i use combobox to fill all user names  temporarly and if i click any name on combobox what are all names that information fill in datagridview i write that code in btn userclik now i want log table by month wise or date i taken two comboboxess and one combox fill datetime picker and one more months i fill ,now i want to click and month i want to show month wise dat in datagridview ,i write that  code search click i am not getting.(dis is in windows forms)one more thng i am not using database also,plz check the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var formatPattern = "dd MMM yyyy hh mm ss";
DateTime parsedDate;
var culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture; // use CurentCulture if you want to use the current culture instead which might change
bool success = DateTime.TryParseExact(dtmDate.Text, formatPattern, culture, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate);
if (success)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a for `DataTable.Select` i would use the `DateTime`  in a Linq-To-DataSet query. You can use `DateTime.TryParseExact` to parse the string to `DateTime`.

```
var formatPattern = "dd MMM yyyy hh mm ss";
DateTime parsedDate;
var culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture; // use CurentCulture if you want to use the current culture instead which might change
bool success = DateTime.TryParseExact(dtmDate.Text, formatPattern, culture, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate);
if (success)
{ 
    // assuming you want all rows of the same day not the same second:
    var filteredRows = tab.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(r => r.Field<DateTime>("Datetime").Date == parsedDate.Date);
    dgv1.DataSource = filteredRows.CopyToDataTable();
}
```